# Azure Search - Using double quotes in a search string

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a requirement that my application should be able to search a string having a double quote in it. For example **22" Wood Log**. Currently, searching for this string returns an error of query being failed.

I understand that using quotes like **"abc"** will give me results for only **abc**. But in the case of **22" Wood Log**, the double quote represent **inches** and user may search like **"22" Wood Log"** expecting to see results for **22" Wood Log**.

What are my options in current scenario to get some results? I hope my question is not too ambiguous.

Comment: Please try by escaping `"` with `\"` and it should work. So your search string would be `22\" Wood Log`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment provided by Gaurav Mantri is correct. You should just escape the special characters in the search query with the backslash `\` character.

For more details and for reference about the querying syntax, please visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search

(You particular query is answered under the Section: **Escaping special characters**)

Comment: This works for me. I will just do some custom parsing for search strings like **"22" Wood Log"** (having three double quotes). Thanks.